# Can't even load a picture in pygame on a black screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying out a jump and run in pygame and I am still a beginner so I have some problems.
The problem I have right now is just that my "hero.bmp" wont open and be printed on my window, but
it doesn't show an error so I don't know what to do.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen.fill((0,0,0))

try:
    player = pygame.image.load('hero.bmp').convert()
except:
    print "please define file 'hero.bmp'"
    sys.exit(1)
playerpos = player.get_rect()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Answer (score 0):

You loaded the image, but you did not actually add them to the screen.

Add " screen.blit(player, (0,0)) " to your code.

This should load your player image to 0,0.

Good luck with pygame!